# Stuck on installing Guest Additions in Windows Host to an Ubuntu Guest on virtualbox (cannot uninstall)

Tags: virtualbox, guest-additions

My host is a Windows 10 machine. On that I've got VirtualBox 7 installed which is running an Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop OS.

VirtualBox gave me the option to insert Guest Additions CD which I tried. It installed Guest additions. Clipboard sharing was working fine. Reboot. Clipboard sharing stopped working.

After that I've spent 2 days trying to uninstall Guest Additions. I've tried to delete the existing installation to the best of my abilities with this:

```
sudo rmmod vboxguest
sudo rm -rf /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-*
sudo find /usr/src -name "*vboxguest*" -exec rm -rf {} +
sudo find /usr/lib -name "*vboxguest*" -exec rm -rf {} +
reboot
```

Now I'm trying to install it again from the CD by following these steps:

- `cd /media/$USER/VBOXADDITIONS_<version>/`
- `sudo sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`

This install doesn't work because it STILL keeps detects an existing installation and tries to uninstall it. This is the output:

```
...
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
/usr/sbin/vbox-uninstall-guest-additions: 9: /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-7.0.12/uninstall.sh: not found
Failed to remove existing installation. Aborting...
```

The folder `/opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-7.0.12` doesn't even exist. Yet it keeps compulsively trying to uninstall from there.

1. Is there a way to force install (overwrite) the guest additions?
2. Why is the installer constantly searching for the existing installation? Is there a way to uninstall all traces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the *guest additions* and *extension pack*:

Start the VirtualBox Manager application.

*Alternative 01:* Install *guest additions* and *extension pack*:

*Update extension pack:* From the munubar of the VirtualBox Manager app, select: **File > Check for Updates...** .

*Update guest additions:* Start a virtual machine, and from the menubar select, **Devices > Upgrade Guest Additions...** and your guest additions will be upgraded, then you can mount the ISO image and proceed with installation.

(*Alternative 02:* If updating from GUI does not work, you can try with CLI. On command line use: `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso` and `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ext-pack` .)

To install guest additions, click on **"Devices" > "Insert Guest Additions CD Image..."** . Then start a file browser e.g. Nautilus (in Ubuntu), Thunar (in Xubuntu). Here, in the side pane, you will see a new CD image been mounted. Click to go into the folder. Now right click and select to open a terminal in this directory. Then you should run the `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` script with sudo privilege, as: `sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` . This will install the guest additions.

Next you'll have to log out and back in. Then you can start VirtualBox machines.

**UPDATE 01:**
*Alternative 03:*
[Source: 4.2.1.2. Updating the Windows Guest Additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html)

Windows Guest Additions can be updated by running the installation program again. This replaces the previous Additions drivers with updated versions.

**VirtualBox Guest Additions - Intro. summary**
The Guest Additions consists of device drivers and some system applications. They offer the following features:

- Mouse pointer integration: Provides seamless mouse support through Host and Guest. No need to to capture the mouse in Guest machine, and pressing Host key to free the pointer.
- Shared folders: Share files between Host and Guest OSs by creating shared folders.
- Seamless windows: Windows displayed on desktop of guest machines can be mapped on the host's desktop. Available in virtual machine menubar. Go to *View > Seamless Mode* or use the shortcut Host+L.
- Shared clipboard: Share the clipboard content between your Guest and Host operating system.

These are some of the features. Read more [here.](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-intro)

**VirtualBox Extension Packs - Intro. summary**
The Extension Packs provide the following functionality:

- USB 2.0 and 3.0 Host Controller
- Host webcam passthrough
- VirtualBox Remote Desktop Protocol (VRDP) support
- Disk image encryption with AES algorithm
- Cloud integration features

More information [here.](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#intro-installing)

Comment: The alternate approach mentioned over here worked!

`Alternative 02: If updating from GUI does not work, you can try with CLI. On command line use: sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso `

I also had to uninstall the leftover remains over here: `rm -rf /usr/sbin/vbox-uninstall-guest-additions` and also had to mount the `virtualbox-guest-additions-iso` image.

I didn't install the extension pack. Any idea whether that's needed or not? Will the guest extension stop working without the extension pack? Like the clipboard share?

Comment: No Extension Pack and Guest Additions are independent of each other. They both add additional functionality to the base VirtualBox installation. I've updated my answer to include a feature summary.

Comment: Thanks a tonne for replying!